# Repeating a complicated sequence and putting the output in a new dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, repeat

I'm relatively new at R, and I've been working for a while to piece together a code that will let me compare 6 variables from two populations drawn from a large data frame (consisting of the original data sampled 1000x with replacement based on pop size).

Here's an example of my data:

```
head(PhenoM2)
 ID         Name    PhenoNames Group   HML    RML    FML    TML   FHD   BIB
1 378607 PaleoAleut PaleoAleut     1  323.5 248.75 434.50 355.75 46.84  NA
2 378664 PaleoAleut PaleoAleut     1   NA   238.50 441.50 353.00 45.83 277.0
3 378377 PaleoAleut PaleoAleut     1  309.5 227.75 419.00 332.25 46.39 284.0
4 378463 PaleoAleut PaleoAleut     1  283.5 228.75 397.75 331.00 44.37 255.5
5 378602 PaleoAleut PaleoAleut     1  279.5 230.00 393.00 329.50 45.93 265.0
6 378610 PaleoAleut PaleoAleut     1  307.5 234.25 419.50 338.50 43.98 271.5
```

My entire code, from the initial resampling loop to output is as follows:

```
samplesM <- ddply(PhenoM2, .(Group),
function(d) d[sample(1:nrow(d), replace = TRUE),])

n <- 1000
samplesM <- vector("list", n)
for (i in seq_along(samplesM)) 
samplesM[[i]] <- ddply(PhenoM2, .(Group),
    function(d) d[sample(1:nrow(d), replace = TRUE),])

all.samplesM <- do.call(rbind, samplesM)

CovDataM <- all.samplesM[,4:10]

covM <- with(CovDataM, by(CovDataM[,2:7], CovDataM$Group, cov, use = "pairwise.complete.obs", method = "pearson"))

cov.aggregator <- function(K){


out <- array(NA,c(6,6,dim(K)))

for(i in 1:dim(K)){

out[,,i] <- K[[i]]

}

return(out)
}


testmatrix<-cov.aggregator(covM)


covM.pooled<-apply(testmatrix,c(1,2), mean, na.rm = T)


male.means<-aggregate(all.samplesM[,4:10], by = list(all.samplesM$"Group"), FUN = mean, na.rm = T)


cov.mstd.aggregator <- function(K,means){


out <- array(NA,c(6,6,dim(K)))

for(i in 1:dim(K)){

mi <- as.matrix(means[i,])
out[,,i] <- K[[i]]/(mi%*%t(mi))

}

return(out)
}


male.P.mstd <- cov.mstd.aggregator(covM,as.matrix(male.means[,3:8]))


covM.mstd.pooled <- apply(male.P.mstd,c(1,2),mean, na.rm = T)

pooledMmean <- apply(male.means[,3:8],2,mean,na.rm=T)

PointHope<-male.means[7,3:8]

Kikuyu<-male.means[128,3:8]

deltaM1<-(PointHope - Kikuyu)/pooledMmean

Pinv <- ginv(covM.mstd.pooled)

B.Kikuyu.PointHope <- Pinv %*% as.matrix(t(deltaM1))
```

I know this is probably very unwieldy, but it works to produce a matrix of the six variables I'm interested in (the HML, RML, FML, TML, FHD, BIB coefficients):

```
B.Kikuyu.PointHope   
      7
[1,] -25.814700
[2,] -79.276511
[3,]   7.517114
[4,] -30.409726
[5,]  59.803203
[6,]  90.246264
```

My questions are as follows: I need the entire code to repeat 10x (from the initial 1000x loop to the output), but I'm not sure how to fit all that ungainly code into a regular for loop or rep() command. I then need the output of each of the 10 repeats to go into an empty dataframe.

I tried tacking this at the end of the original code to be repeated, but without the [,i] it simply rewrote Kikuyu.PointHope.df every time I (manually) repeated it, and with the [,i] I recieved an error.

```
Kikuyu.PointHope.df[,i] <- do.call(rbind, as.list(B.Kikuyu.PointHope))
```

If possible, I'd like the output (which is listed in a column) to be inserted as a row in the new dataframe, just as shown in the initial data above. I've tried several iterations of cbind and rbind with little effect.

Thank you for your time, sorry for the long question. I'm sure this is relatively basic, the length of the existing code is tripping me up.

Comment: If all you're asking is how to repeat a bunch of stuff, the easiest way is to bundle everything you posted into a "wrapper" function, then you could do `sapply(1:10,function(j) my_wrapper(your_arguments, subscripted to j_th group of data) )`

Comment: Thanks - once I figure out how to construct a wrapper, that will definitely help with the repeats! But the output will still be the same column of matrix data - any ideas on how to make that a row in a dataframe to which I can keep adding output? Sorry for all the questions, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Posting comment as answer, as OP seems satisfied :-)

If all you're asking is how to repeat a bunch of stuff, the easiest way is to bundle everything you posted into a "wrapper" function, then you could do `sapply(1:10,function(j) my_wrapper(your_arguments, subscripted to j_th group of data) )`